# Is there a limit to how much health I can have?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac

In The Binding of Isaac, what is the maximum amount of health I can get? Is there even a limit?

The [health display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51Hmx.png) in the upper-right corner has space for a maximum of 12 hearts. However, during a couple separate runs, I got so many hearts that I exceeded this visual limit, and apparently Soul/Faith Hearts collected after that do count, as when I took damage, it didn't show up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Heart containers (red hearts) stack to a maximum of 12 hearts (24 normal hits before the womb, after which it's 12 hits).

However, soul hearts have no limit (I personally have collected over 200 soul hearts using the battery/xray glasses/book of revelations trick). Even if they surpass what can be physically seen, they will still act in the same way as all of your other soul hearts, with the invisible hearts being consumed first.